# vertical align text in several li tag with float:left attribute

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

i want to set vertical-align:midle; for text into li tags.this in my code but it doesn't work...

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="container">
<ul id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">AAAA </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">BBB BBB</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">CCC </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">DD</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">FFFFF</li>
</ul>
<div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#container{position:relative; top:30px;}

#selectable{ list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 450px;
    display:table;  }

#selectable li{width:80px;
    height:80px;
    margin:4px;
    padding:8px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;}`
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: When you float an element, the `display` property (default or specified) is ignored.  The vertical-align is being ignored as well because it is no longer being applied to an inline or table-cell element.

Comment: How important is it to have the `li` elements be 80px tall?

Comment: I've been trying things in jsFiddle for you. But found no solution other than setting line-height.. Maybe you find a satisfying method on the link I have given in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your `line-height` equal to the `height` of the `<li>`element.

```
#selectable li {
    line-height:80px;
    /* ... your own properties */
}
```

Should work on all browsers

In addition a [link](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) on how to vertically align.
And a link to a working [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Cgd74/)

Comment: It works until your content is too wide for their container:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cgd74/1/

Comment: If you set a width to the list you should set it that way your text fits in. ugly solution: `overflow:scroll` .. Else you should make your list elements wider OR drop your float as cimmanon suggested.

Comment: i cant wider list element & if drop float frome li tags the white space between their is be remove.

Comment: with `display:inline-block` you should add margin. Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `vertical-align:middle;` and have a horizontal menu, try using `display:inline-block;`:

```
#selectable li{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    margin:4px;
    padding:8px;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    /* for IE7- */
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

This `display:inline-block` is generally [considered a more appropriate choice](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/) for most items like this nowadays.

**EDIT: Totally misread the header**

You want the TEXT vertically aligned. My bad. set the line-height equal to the height of the parent (in this case, `#selectable li`). The CSS above has been edited to include this.

Comment: His list elements would end up next to each other... Vertical-align is mostly used for real tables. If you really must use it: set `display:table-cell;`!

Comment: the parent has a fixed width. it would automatically wrap the items, not overflow.

Comment: However your solution does not work as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBKyM/)

Comment: i totally misread the headline ... you wanted the text vertically aligned. edited my answer to show `line-height` must be the same as `height`. updated your jsFiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox looks like it might be your only option for the requirements you have.  Browser support:  Opera, Chrome, IE10.  You can drop in as many `li` elements as you want.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/mxuFa

```
#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 450px;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; /* fallback */
  display: -webkit-inline-flexbox;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It is safe to float/inline-block the `li` elements as a fallback for browsers who don't support Flexbox, it just won't have the proper vertical-alignment.

Comment: Indeed but these modern times scream for xbrowser websites :-) He would be better off using a real `<table>`Lol

Comment: Except for the part where the ability to wrap is a requirement.  If the OP didn't need the elements to be a specific height, the CSS would be half as long.